# PHP Variables get overwritten to Null

Tags: php, session

I'm having issues maintaining variables in the Session.  I've confirmed that the same Session ID persists through page navigation, and I've also used the `Print_r($_SESSION)` to monitor the variables.

I'm using four pages.

- index.php
- custinfo.php
- custbilling.php
- confirm.php

On the first page I'm using a form to send data to the next page.

```
        <form name="prescreen" action="custinfo.php" method="post">
        <label>From DIA</label>
        <input name="startlocation" id="fromdia" type="radio" value="From DIA">
        <label>To DIA</label>
        <input name="startlocation" id="todia" type="radio" value="To DIA">
        <label>Choose Location:</label>
        City:<input name="city" id="city" type="text" />
        <span>or</span><br />
        Zipcode:<input name="zipcode" id="zipcode" type="text" />
    <h3>When do you need picked up?</h3>
        <label>Choose Date:</label>
        <input name="date" id="date" type="datetime-local" />
        <label>Choose Time:</label>
        <input name="time" id="time" type="time" />
    <input type="submit"  value="Get a Ride Now!" class="textbtn"></input>
    </form>
```

On custinfo.php, I then use this in the head of the document:

```
 <?php
    session_start();

    $_SESSION['testvar'] = 'THIS IS A TEST';
    $startlocation = $_POST["startlocation"];
    $city = $_POST["city"];
    $zipcode = $_POST["zipcode"];
    $date = $_POST["date"];
    $time = $_POST["time"];

    //Assign variables to the Session
    $_SESSION['startlocation'] = $startlocation;
    $_SESSION['city'] = $city;
    $_SESSION['zipcode'] = $zipcode;
    $_SESSION['date'] = $date;
    $_SESSION['time'] = $time;

?>
```

The variables are properly read in and stored in the array.  Then I use this form in the custinfo.php page:

```
        <form name="customerinfo" action="custbilling.php" method="post">
        <label>Contact Name</label>
        <input name="contactname" id="contactname" type="text">
        <label>Contact Email</label>
        <input name="contactemail" id="contactemail" type="text">
        <label>Contact Phone</label>
        <input name="contactphone" id="contactphone" type="text" />
        <?php
        if($_SESSION['startlocation'] == "From DIA")
        {
            echo '<hr />';
            echo '<label><b>To Location:</b></label>';
            echo 'Address1:<input name="toaddress1" id="toaddress1" type="text" />';
            echo 'Address2:<input name="toaddress2" id="toaddress2" type="text" />';
            echo 'City:<input name="tocity" id="tocity" type="text" />';
            echo 'Zip:<input name="tozip" id="tozip" type="text"  />';
            echo '<hr />';
        }
        else
        {
            echo '<hr />';
            echo '<label><b>From Location</b></label>';
            echo 'Address1:<input name="fromaddress1" id="fromaddress1" type="text" />';
            echo 'Address2:<input name="fromaddress2" id="fromaddress2" type="text" />';
            echo 'City:<input name="fromcity" id="fromcity" type="text" />';
            echo 'Zip:<input name="fromzip" id="fromzip" type="text" />';
            echo '<hr />';
        }

        ?>

        <input type="submit"  value="Book Your Ride!" class="textbtn"></input>
        </form>
```

In the head of the custbilling.php page I have everything pulling in like so:

```
<?php
session_start();

/*Vars from Customer Info */
$contactname = $_POST['contactname'];
$contactemail = $_POST['contactemail'];
$contactphone = $_POST['contactphone'];
if($_SESSION['startlocation'] == "To DIA")
{
    $address1 = $_POST['fromaddress1'];
    $address2 = $_POST['fromaddress2'];
    $city = $_POST['fromcity'];
    $zipcode = $_POST['fromzip'];
}
else
{
    $address1 = $_POST['toaddress1'];
    $address2 = $_POST['toaddress2'];
    $city = $_POST['tocity'];
    $zipcode =$_POST['tozip'];
}

//Assign Variables to the Session
$_SESSION['contactname'] = $contactname;
$_SESSION['contactemail'] = $contactemail;
$_SESSION['contactphone'] = $contactphone;
$_SESSION['address1']=$address1;
$_SESSION['address2']=$address2;
$_SESSION['city']= $city;
$_SESSION['zipcode'] = $zipcode;

?>
```

At this point, I'm displaying the information like so:\

```
<h1><?php echo $_SESSION['testvar']; ?></h1>
    <h2>Travel Information</h2>
    <h3>Please fill out this form:</h3>
    <p>Direction of Travel: <?php echo $_SESSION['startlocation']; ?></p>
    <p>LocationTo: <?php echo $_SESSION['city'] , $_SESSION['zipcode']; ?></p>
    <p>Date: <?php echo $_SESSION['date']; ?></p>
    <p>Time: <?php echo $_SESSION['time']; ?></p>
    <p>Customer Name: <?php echo $_SESSION['contactname']; ?></p>
    <p>Customer Email: <?php echo $_SESSION['contactemail']; ?></p>
    <p>Customer Phone: <?php echo $_SESSION['contactphone']; ?></p>
    <p>Address Information: <br />
        <span>Address 1:</span><?php echo $_SESSION['address1']; ?><br />
        <span>Address 2:</span><?php echo $_SESSION['address2']; ?><br />
        <span>City:</span><?php echo $_SESSION['city']; ?><br />
        <span>ZipCode:</span><?php echo $_SESSION['zipcode']; ?><br />
    </p>
```

But the startlocation and all the variables from the first post that were saved in the array are now erased.  You can also see the testvariable that I used to test that the session was working, and my `$_SESSION['testvar']` Displays properly on ALL of the files.  I initially had the code set like so `$_SESSION['varname] = $_POST['varname'];`, but that produced the same issue.  So the variable would go to the next page, but it wouldn't continue to the third page.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you.

EDIT:  This might be useful information:

```
Result from custinfo.php : bs2rrqoo5u1u5mjerkg54nkcb1 Array ( [startlocation] => From DIA [city] => Denver [zipcode] => [date] => 11/27/2012 [time] => 09:00 [fromaddress1] => [fromaddress2] => [fromcity] => [fromzip] => [toaddress1] => [toaddress2] => [tocity] => [tozip] => [contactname] => [contactemail] => [contactphone] => [address1] => [address2] => [testvar] => THIS IS A TEST [sameaddress] => 1 [billaddress1] => [billaddress2] => [billcity] => [billzip] => [ccnumber] => [ccexp] => [ccsc] => )

Result from custbilling.php : bs2rrqoo5u1u5mjerkg54nkcb1 Array ( [startlocation] => [city] => Aurora [zipcode] => 80017 [date] => [time] => [fromaddress1] => [fromaddress2] => [fromcity] => [fromzip] => [toaddress1] => [toaddress2] => [tocity] => [tozip] => [contactname] => Elijah Gartin [contactemail] => elijah.gartin@gmail.com [contactphone] => 3038804117 [address1] => 124 Test [address2] => [testvar] => THIS IS A TEST [sameaddress] => 1 [billaddress1] => [billaddress2] => [billcity] => [billzip] => [ccnumber] => [ccexp] => [ccsc] => )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was on the server.  I had to add `session.save_path = "/var/location"` to the php.ini file.  Thanks for trying guys.

Answer (score 1):

Conflicting sessions result in `null` values.

Try using global variables or communicating the values through a persistant data structure.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by conflicting sessions?  The session ID is the same for each portion, so I'm not sure if that was overlooked?  I was trying to avoid using global variables, but what do you mean when you say, "Communicating the values through a persistent data structure"?

Answer (score 0):

Session variables won't survive going from http to https.

Comment: I don't understand how this is true when one of my variables survives the entire time?  Or are you saying the problem is with index.php?  If so then I'm assuming I need to figure out a way to force index.php to have https?

Actually, none of the pages are currently under https... I forced the index to use https, and all hell broke loose. (Since I hadn't configured a SSL Cert)